# hook NSFileManager::fileExistsAtPath (Jailbreak Tweak learning)

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I am (trying to) learn developing a jailbreak tweak. Objective is to get rid of the jailbreak protection in an Application (refused to work with Jailbreak).

I have decompiled the app and have identified the following code as the "jailbreak check":

```
  v24 = objc_msgSend(&OBJC_CLASS___NSMutableDictionary, "new");
  v0 = "defaultManager";
  v1 = objc_msgSend(&OBJC_CLASS___NSFileManager, "defaultManager");
  v2 = objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue(v1);
  v3 = (void *)v2;
  v23 = v2;
  v4 = (int)"stringWithFormat:";
  v5 = objc_msgSend(
         &OBJC_CLASS___NSString,
         "stringWithFormat:",
         CFSTR("/%@%@%@%@%@%@%@"),
         CFSTR("App"),
         CFSTR("lic"),
         CFSTR("ati"),
         CFSTR("ons/"),
         CFSTR("Cyd"),
         CFSTR("ia."),
         CFSTR("app"));
  v6 = objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue(v5);
  v7 = v6;
  v8 = objc_msgSend(v3, "fileExistsAtPath:", v6);
  if ( (unsigned __int8)v8 )
  {
    v9 = 1;
    v10 = 0;
    v21 = v8;
    v11 = 0;
    v22 = (void *)v8;
  }
```

The application checks for existance of /Applications/Cydia.app

Here is the code of Tweak.xm:

```
%hook NSFileManager

- (BOOL)fileExistsAtPath:(NSString *)path{
    if ([path rangeOfString:@"cydia"].location == NSNotFound) {
        return %orig (path);
    } else {
        %log
        return FALSE;
    }
}

%end
```

Although I can see from syslog that other files are being checked, I do not see that we're checking for /Applications/Cydia.app. Is this is a problem with my code or is it simply that for other reason this code is never executed?

Comment: You are checking for the string `@"cydia"`, all lowercase, while the method will be called with a path containing `@"Cydia"`, with an uppercase `C`

Comment: @stonesam92: I already tried to use %log always but nothing in the log

Comment: Even with the `%log` as the first line of the function? (Currently the `%log` statement will never be reached, since it is in a block which will only be executed if the argument contains `@"cydia"`)

Comment: Could it be related to the code getting the defaultManager instance of class NSFileManager ?

Comment: No, you're hooking an instance method, so any instance of NSFileManager should use your replacement method. If you attach a debugger to the process and set a breakpoint on the method, can you verify that it ever actually gets called?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change "jailbreak check" method to do nothing.

```
%hook ClassName
- (void)jailbreakCheck {
}
%end
```